# Missing @AnnotationDrivenTx Spring3

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-3

my collegues sais i should convert the spring's app-context.xml into java.

For that i need to have the @AnnotationDrivenTx-Annotation i cant find.

Any workaround here?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean [`@EnableTransactionManagement`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html)

See http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/10/spring-3-1-m2-configuration-enhancements/

Answer (score 0):

You could download it as separate jar from a MavenRepository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.javaconfig</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.m3</version>
</dependency>
```

But it´s from 2008 and seems not to be developed anymore. 
These features can be found in spring-tx component and @EnableTransactionManagement is the way to go as Charles said.